# Python: Function call as a parameter

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to make a function as:

```
def func (model_name = 'abc', **kwargs):
  model = model_name (**kwargs)
  model.do_something ()
```

So the model will be created based on the value of the parameter `model_name`.

Comment: So `'abc'` is the name of a function here?  You can simply pass the function as an argument and call *that* instead, so change to `func(model_name=abc, **kwargs)`

Comment: cool, it is awesome